# Alleviate/reduce/relieve/diminish/lessen

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

Which verb is more appropriate in this context?

She found solace in books to ___ her grief/resentment (alleviate/reduce/relieve/diminish/lessen or whatever is more suitable)

Comment: 'Suppress' fits the bill.

Comment: The syntax is a bit awkward. With more natural phrasing, perhaps it would be easier to think of the appropriate word. For example: *She found solace in books; reading helped to lessen her grief.*

Comment: It doesn't help that ***grief*** and ***resentment*** are quite different things - although they can both be "reduced, made less troublesome", the actions that might achieve this are often different, so many of the verbs that could work with ***grief*** don't work so well with ***resentment***, and vice-versa. Personally, I think a couple of turns of phrase that work for both are *...to **keep** her [grief and resentment] **in check*** and ***hold** [those emotions] **at bay***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reading your verbs I thought of another: ***assuage*** which goes well with ***grief*** and ***solace***.

[Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alleviate%20grief%2Cassuage%20grief%2Crelieve%20grief%2Creduce%20grief%2Cdiminish%20grief%2C%20lessen%20grief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calleviate%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassuage%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelieve%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creduce%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiminish%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clessen%20grief%3B%2Cc0) actually agrees that ***assuage*** is more commonly used with "grief" than all the verbs you mentioned:

[image]

However, the percentages are discouragingly low, so I guess all these phrases are rarely used.

I found that to [suppress resentment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alleviate%20resentment%2Csuppress%20resentment&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calleviate%20resentment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppress%20resentment%3B%2Cc0) is more common.

Comment: "Assuage" is spot-on but just wondering if it's used by native speakers or is it a literary word?

Comment: I do use it in literary writings, it is quite poetic. I thinK it is a verb native speakers would use, but it is rather formal. See its definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assuage).

Comment: Also [suppress grief](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suppress+resentment%2Csuppress+grief%2Csuppressed+grief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuppress%20resentment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppress%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppressed%20grief%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Void:. Yes, it comes [third](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alleviate+grief%2Cassuage+grief%2Crelieve+grief%2Creduce+grief%2Cdiminish+grief%2Clessen+grief%2C+suppress+grief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calleviate%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassuage%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelieve%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creduce%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiminish%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clessen%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppress%20grief%3B%2Cc0) in comparison with the other verbs.

Comment: For at least the whole of *my* life, the collocation ***assuage guilt*** has been more common than all your examples put together. If only for that reason, I think I'd hesitate to use ***assuage*** for anything else.

Comment: @FF: if you look up this word in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assuage), you  will find this example: "The government has tried to assuage the public's fears." But as I said in my answer, it is true that the percentages of use are so low that maybe the OP should look for another way of expressing this. _**Stop greif**_ is much more common apparently.

Comment: Well, I searched [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) for **to * her grief**, to see what words are most common in that context. It turns out ***assuage*** is actually ***the*** most common verb having the sense "lessen, soften" (as opposed to the senses of "express" and "conceal"), so maybe it's not so odd as I first thought. I'd still avoid it myself though. Apart from anything else, an "ordinary" word like ***soften*** works perfectly well with ***grief*** AND ***resentment*** (OP mentions both), but imho ***assuage*** is an absolutely terrible partner with ***resentment***.

Comment: @FF: I am impressed by your research and I am learning from you. Thanks for sharing. It was not clear if the OP was asking for a verb which would agree with both "grief" and "resentment" in the **same** sentence. I absolutely agree that "assuage" does not dance well with "resentment".

Comment: (That's not a particularly good choice of example usage by Cambridge, either. Idiomatically, the public's fears are much more likely to be ***allayed***, not ***assuaged**!* :)

Comment: @FF: I am sure you are right. Maybe they should be told...